# Prove: If $|z|<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow |(1+i)z^3+iz|<\frac{3}{4},z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove: If $|z|<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow |(1+i)z^3+iz|<\frac{3}{4},z\in\mathbb{C}$

$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow x^2+y^2 <\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

$$|(1+i)z^3+iz|=|(x^3-3xy-3x^2y-y-y^3)+i(x^3-3xy+3x^2y+x-y^3)|=\sqrt{(x^3-3xy-3x^2y-y-y^3)^2+(x^3-3xy+3x^2y+x-y^3)^2}$$

Is there another approach rather than expanding these expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Assuming $z=ai$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$|(1+i)(ai)^3+i(ai)|<\frac{3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$|(1+i)(ai)^3-a|<\frac{3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$|(1-i)a^3-a|<\frac{3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$|a((1+i)a^2-i)|<\frac{3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$|a||(1+i)a^2-i|<\frac{3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sqrt{a^6+(a^3-a)^2}<\frac{3}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint
$$|(1+i)z^3+iz|\le |(1+i)||z|^3+|iz|<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{8}+\dfrac{1}{2}<\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{3}{4}$$